# Wordpress update_post_meta does not update dynamic values

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

This is a little strange, I am using "update_post_meta" to update the custom fields in Wordpress. When I run update_post_meta($post_id, 'Test_Field', 'Test Value'); the custom field updates without a problem BUT when I use a string value it does not update:

```
$test_value = "Test";
 echo $test_value; // No problem here
 echo $post_id; // No problem here
 update_post_meta($post_id, 'Test_Field', $test_value);
```

Thanks very much in advance for your help

Stu

Comment: Double quotes fixed it, but anyone know why?
update_post_meta("$page_id", "Test_Field", "$test_value");

Comment: how are you assigning $post_id? Just guessing - everything looks fine, frankly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to cast variables with types. Try this:

```
update_post_meta( (int) $post_id, 'Test_Field', (string) $test_value );
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first example used $post_id and solution $page_id. Was that a typo?

Answer (score 1):

It might sound strange but, meta_key name must be identical to the input field name.

`update_post_meta( $post_id, 'top_image', $_POST['top_image'] );`